# How long is data in localStorage kept?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript you have the object `localStorage`.

How long this object will be active for? How long is the the data in it kept for?

Comment: You want to know how long the data in localstorage remains there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most correct answer to this question is: You don't know.

The user could wipe his/her local data at any time, and any type of local storage is subject to user preferences and to be considered extremely volatile. However, there is **no defined expiration time**, according to Web Storage specifications:

> **Expiring stored data**
>
> > User agents may, if so configured by the user, automatically delete stored data after a period of time.
> >
> > For example, a user agent could be configured to treat third-party local storage areas as session-only storage, deleting the data once the user had closed all the browsing contexts that could access it.
> >
> > This can restrict the ability of a site to track a user, as the site would then only be able to track the user across multiple sessions when he authenticates with the site itself (e.g. by making a purchase or logging in to a service).
> >
> > However, this also reduces the usefulness of the API as a long-term storage mechanism. It can also put the user's data at risk, if the user does not fully understand the implications of data expiration.

Source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/